# Latex font package used here

Tags: fonts, packages

[image: example]

I am trying to figure out what package/font was used to typeset this example and I cannot really recognise it. I figured I'd ask some of you as you'd probab

Comment: If it is done with LaTeX, you might want to read out the PDF meta data with your PDF-reader. It shoud be mentioned there.

Comment: huh? which part do you not recognise? that looks like the standard font to me.

Comment: Yep, checked with a simple 5-line document - all of this is the default Computer Modern, which you get without any packages. But for any other fonts, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: Ok, sorry I'll just delete it.